# zxing/library unable to scan UPC-E barcode

Tags: barcode, zxing, zxing-js

zxing/library can't find the UPC-E barcode

```
 const hints = new Map()
 const formats = [
       BarcodeFormat.UPC_A,
       BarcodeFormat.UPC_E,
       BarcodeFormat.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION,
 ]

 hints.set(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats)

 const scanner = new BrowserMultiFormatReader(hints)
 const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'environment' }})
 const result = await scanner.decodeOnceFromStream(stream, 'video').catch(() => null)
```

It sucessfully scans UPC_A and UPC_EAN, but not the UPC_E

This is what I am trying to scan
[image]

The library version is 0.20.0

I have tried on multiple devices, non of them succeeded

Do I have to do something special to make it work or the library has problems?

Comment: I see you opened an issue on Github as well, however from the other issues there (https://github.com/zxing-js/library/issues?q=is%3Aissue+UPC-E) it seems that the UPC-E support does not really work. [There is one mention](https://github.com/zxing-js/library/issues/314#issuecomment-714669352) by the maintainer of implementing "experimental support" in a `dev` release but without any details on the scope of the functionality or whether it has been incorporated in any further releases or not.

Comment: @Marijn It is on their README.md on github https://github.com/zxing-js/library#supported-formats. UPC-E is listed in the supported formats.

Comment: I saw that, but that doesn't mean it actually works - going from the various Github issues it seems that the support for this format in fact does not work, unfortunately.